# AWS: Delete lambda layer still retains layer version history

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-lambda-layers

I am deploying a AWS Lambda layer using aws cli:

```
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name my_layer --zip-file fileb://my_layer.zip
```

I delete it using

```
VERSION=$(aws lambda list-layer-versions --layer-name my_layer | jq '.LayerVersions[0].Version'
aws lambda delete-layer-version --layer-name my_layer --version-number $VERSION
```

Deletes successfully, ensured no other version of the layer exists.

```
aws lambda list-layer-versions --layer-name my_layer
>
{
    "LayerVersions": []
}
```

Upon next publishing of the layer, it still retains history of previous version. From what I read if no layer version exists and no reference exists, the version history should be gone, but I don't see that. Anybody have a solution to HARD delete the layer with its version?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. What I'm trying to achieve is to "reset" the version count to 1 in order to match code versioning and tags on my repo. Currently, the only way I found is to publish a new layer with a new name.

I think AWS Lambda product lacks of features that help (semantic) versioning.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there's no way to do this. Layer Versions are immutable, they cannot be updated or modified, you can only delete and publish new layer versions. Once a layer version is 'stamped' -- there is no way (AFAIK) that you can go back and get back that layer version.

It might be that after a while (weeks...months?) AWS delete it's memory of the layer version, but as it stands, the version number assigned to any deleted layer cannot be assumed by any new layer.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problem with layer versions. Do you have suggestions for simple way out instead of writing code to check available versions out there and pick latest one...

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue, As there was no aws-cli command to delete the layer itself,I had delete all versions of my lambda-layer using:

```
aws lambda delete-layer-version --layer-name test_layer --version-number 1
```

After deleting all versions of the layer, the layer was not showing in aws lambda layers page,So I thought its successfully deleted.

But to my surprise,AWS stills keeps the data about our deleted layers(at-least the last version for sure), when you try create a lambda layer with your previous deleted lambda name using aws gui or cli, the version will not start from 1, instead it starts from last_version of assumed to be deleted layer.